# Renumber dynamic column without update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this data

```
5 | Batman
5 | Superman
5 | Wonderwomen
6 | Green Lantern
6 | Green Arrow
7 | Cyborg
```

when I do select query, I want renumber to

```
1 | Batman
1 | Superman
1 | Wonderwomen
2 | Green Lantern
2 | Green Arrow
3 | Cyborg
```

thought?

**EDIT:**

thanks to vittore, so i came up with this solution. I'm not sure if my query is good.
I do **ROW_NUMBER()** twice. In case my sequence Id is jumping, this query will renumbering perfectly.

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id asc) AS CteId
FROM MyTable
)
 SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CteId ORDER BY CteId asc) AS RenumberColumn
 FROM cte
```

Comment: Is there some logic to determine this renumbering?

Comment: no, I just want to reset the value from 1.

Comment: Okay question two. Why bother?

Comment: because it would act like rank. I cannot do update all the time, so the other option is change my select query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function is what you are looking for

```
select RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id), name
from t
```

Check [row_number()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [dense_rank()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) when you reading about it as well.

**UPDATE**:  If you just use rank alone, it will give you not the values you want ( 1 1 1 2 2 3 ), but ranked values ( 1 1 1 4 4 6 )

So in order to get (1 2 3) group, rank and join:

```
  select a.r, t.name from t  
      inner join (select id, rank() over (order by id asc) r 
                  from t group by id) a 
         on t.id = a.id
```

Comment: Hi vittore, thanks for your thought. it really help me a lot. can you check my Edit please? I'm not sure it would same as your syntax.

Comment: @vantian you can do it with two row_number or with one rank, as i did it in  second snippet. what i would do is take a look at actual execution plan for both on your database to check if there is advance of one over another on you actual data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always -4, then:

```
Select (number-4), name
from table
```

But I doubt it's that simple.